# Comparing the class body in JCodeModel with the body of a .java file

Tags: java, class, comparison, equality, jcodemodel

I have a `JCodeModel` object which includes a class body, would be written to a `.java` file:

```
codeModel.build(new File("src").getAbsoluteFile());
```

There might already be the same `.java` class file in the folder, which I tend to compare with the current `JcodeModel`'s object content, and save this `JCodeModel` to `.java` file **only if the class body has been updated and differs from the old `.java` file**.

I couldn't find any way to do this with `JCodeModel`'s default methods. How should this be done? Comparing the **fields** of the two classes should also do the job in my case, But a more general way to compare the whole bodies of the classes would be preferable.